# Possible to download ALL attachments from all my customer accounts in one go?

Tags: document, admin

Having a Legal review of my customers accounts where we store all the signed legal agreements inside.
Is there any known way to download all attachments from my 300+ Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the Salesforce Data Export tool; see [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_implementation_data_management/lex_implementation_data_export)

The attachments [will be downloaded](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_exportdata.htm&type=5) if you

> Select Include images, documents, and attachments and Include Salesforce Files and Salesforce CRM Content document versions to include these items in your export data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to download all files/attachments (signed legal agreements in your case) from Accounts (or any Standard or Custom Object) in one go using Satrang Mass File Download AppExchange App: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.